# Accessing a file on an android device using asp.net webpage in chrome

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp web page which needs to grab an xls file from the device storage area on my android tablet, convert it into bytes and store it in my SQL database.

I can do the converting and storing bit but I have no idea as to how to get the file using VB.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the file without the user having to search for it using an upload control?

I would also like to delete the file after processing..

Thank you..

Derek.

Answer (score 0):

In order to think about this we need to have clear in our minds where the division between client and server exists: You've got a webserver running ASP and a client running a webbrowser on the android platform.

The file you are trying to upload exists on the client.  As such any code which does the uploading will have to run on the client and, as the client is running on android, it's unlikely it'll be VB doing the uploading.  You're likely to need to use a scripting language like Javascript and, if you care about cross-browser support, be careful how you do it.

The server cannot get the file directly from the client due to common security restrictions.

Once the client side script has got the file, it'd usually send the data to the server using a webservice or other endpoint, deletion of the file can then happen after that.

Comment: Thank you for your response..  I am new to javascript so I better get my head in some books.  Will let you know how I get on :)

Comment: Awesome.  Once you've had a dig, if you hit difficulties, you can always ask another more specific question and link people back to this one for context.

Comment: Thanks again GHC, we are now building a native Android app..  happy days!!